# Android Users' Cellphone Plan Info

Tags: android

I am currently building an Android app in which I would like to get access to information about the users' cellphone plans.  Is there a way that I can do this to any extent within the app or will I have to manually request this information from my users?  Even if I can only get some information, that would be useful.  Ultimately, I would like to know what plan they currently have and how much they are paying for it.

Comment: That's way out of reach from within the context of an app. The most you can get is the network operator's name (carrier) and the phone number.

Comment: Can I find out what their talk, text, or data limit is?

Comment: Nope. That's all in the carrier's realm.